# Ansible keyword - throttle

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use and understand how throttle keyword works.

Below is how I am using it (test-playbook.yaml).

```
---
- name: Test throttle
  hosts: all
  
  tasks:

    # list of pre tasks
    
    - name: Execute sequentially
      throttle: 1
      block:
        - include_tasks: task-1.yaml
        
        - include_tasks: task-2.yaml
        
        # a task using some module
        
        # a task using some module

    # list of post tasks
```

Executed `ansible-playbook --inventory some-inventory --limit host1:host2:host3`

I am expecting that at task **(Execute sequentially)**, all the hosts specified in --limit will execute sequentially i.e. host1 will complete all tasks in the block, then host2 followed by host3

But they are executed in parallel (default Ansible behavior).

Can someone help in understanding ***throttle*** behavior? Have I missed some configuration?

`forks/serial` have default values.

And how can I achieve sequential behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [behavior](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#controlling-playbook-execution-strategies-and-more) of *ansible-playbook* is the [linear strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/linear_strategy.html#ansible-builtin-linear-executes-tasks-in-a-linear-fashion):

> Task execution is in lockstep per host batch as defined by **serial (default all)**. Up to the **fork limit** of hosts will execute **each task at the same time** and then the next series of hosts **until the batch is done, before going on to the next task**.

[throttle](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#restricting-execution-with-throttle) serves the purpose of "*limiting the number of workers for a particular task ... Use throttle to restrict tasks that may be CPU-intensive or interact with a rate-limiting API*".

For example, by default execute the task in parallel at all (limited by [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) up to the [forks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-number-of-forks)) hosts

```yaml
- hosts: host1,host2,host3
  tasks:
    - command: sleep 1
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} task1
              {{ result.start }} - {{ result.end }}"
```

You can see that all hosts executed the task in parallel

```yaml
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 task1 2021-07-23 08:56:14.735263 - 2021-07-23 08:56:15.759474
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 task1 2021-07-23 08:56:14.743419 - 2021-07-23 08:56:15.759518
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 task1 2021-07-23 08:56:14.475249 - 2021-07-23 08:56:15.551159
```

If you limit the execution by *throttle*

```yaml
    - command: sleep 1
      register: result
      throttle: 1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} task2
              {{ result.start }} - {{ result.end }}"
```

You can see that the execution of the task was serialized

```yaml
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 task2 2021-07-23 08:56:20.252623 - 2021-07-23 08:56:21.312210
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 task2 2021-07-23 08:56:22.688410 - 2021-07-23 08:56:23.744130
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 task2 2021-07-23 08:56:17.937011 - 2021-07-23 08:56:18.955631
```

Make sure the time has been synchronized before you start experimenting.

---

Q: *"**Using include_tasks I am not getting the same behavior. All the included tasks are running in parallel.**"*

A: I can't reproduce your problem. Given the files

```yaml
shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.10.1

shell> cat test-119-tasks-2.yml
---
- command: sleep 1
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} task2
          {{ result.start }} - {{ result.end }}"

shell> cat test-119-tasks-3.yml
---
- command: sleep 1
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} task3
          {{ result.start }} - {{ result.end }}"
```

the task

```yaml
    - name: Execute sequentially
      throttle: 1
      block:
        - include_tasks: test-119-tasks-2.yml
        - include_tasks: test-119-tasks-3.yml
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-119-tasks-2.yml for host1, host2, host3
TASK [command] *****************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
changed: [host3]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 task2 2021-07-25 10:56:11.832219 - 2021-07-25 10:56:12.848834
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 task2 2021-07-25 10:56:14.312498 - 2021-07-25 10:56:15.330202
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 task2 2021-07-25 10:56:16.751018 - 2021-07-25 10:56:17.774723

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-119-tasks-3.yml for host1, host2, host3

TASK [command] ******************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
changed: [host3]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: host1 task3 2021-07-25 10:56:20.373052 - 2021-07-25 10:56:21.405847
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: host2 task3 2021-07-25 10:56:22.761254 - 2021-07-25 10:56:23.788941
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: host3 task3 2021-07-25 10:56:25.134650 - 2021-07-25 10:56:26.151786
```

You can see that the execution of the included tasks was serialized. This works as expected because the keyword *throttle* is allowed in the [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#block). The application of such keyword to a block is the same as the application of this keyword to all tasks in the block.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I tried it and worked as you said but did you try using `include_tasks`? I am not getting the same behavior. All the included tasks are running in parallel.

Comment: You're welcome. It works for me. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Tried your example and working as expected. Need to check where am doing wrong.